# SIGSEGV SEGV_MAPERR crash in my iOS app

Tags: ios, segmentation-fault, iphone-64bit

I am getting SIGSEGV SEGV_MAPERR crash in my live iOS app. 
These crashes weren't there when my app was 32 bit. Since I made my app 64 bit compatible, these crashes started coming.
Also, the iOS devices that report these errors are 64 bit. So, no errors on 32 bit devices.

Please help me out. This crash is deteriorating my app's performance. They occur quite frequently.

Following stack trace is reported by Crittercism.

```
Crashed Thread
0     libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000196703bd0 objc_msgSend + 12
1     CoreFoundation 0x0000000184951458 CFRelease + 520
2     QuartzCore 0x0000000188e24ad8 CA::release_objects() + 28
3     QuartzCore 0x0000000188e2aaec -[CAAnimation dealloc] + 80
4     CoreFoundation 0x0000000184951458 CFRelease + 520
5     QuartzCore 0x0000000188e2d634 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks() + 300
6     libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000196d6d954 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
7     libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000196d7220c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1604
8     CoreFoundation 0x0000000184a2b7f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
9     CoreFoundation 0x0000000184a298a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1488
10     CoreFoundation 0x00000001849552d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
11     GraphicsServices 0x000000018e3b36fc GSEventRunModal + 164
12     UIKit 0x0000000189552f40 UIApplicationMain + 1484
13     My App 0x00000001000f2a7c main (main.m:19)
14     libdyld.dylib 0x0000000196d9aa08 start + 0


14 other threads

Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196e98c24 kevent64 + 4
1     libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000196d6f99c _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196eb3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 4
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef0 start_wqthread + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196eb3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 4
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef0 start_wqthread + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196eb3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 4
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef0 start_wqthread + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196eb3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 4
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef0 start_wqthread + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196eb3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 4
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef0 start_wqthread + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196eb3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 4
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef0 start_wqthread + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196e98e0c mach_msg_trap + 4
1     CoreFoundation 0x0000000184a2b724 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
2     CoreFoundation 0x0000000184a29678 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
3     CoreFoundation 0x00000001849552d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
4     CFNetwork 0x0000000184432594 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 436
5     Foundation 0x0000000185975db8 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
6     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4fdc8 _pthread_body + 160
7     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4fd24 _pthread_start + 156
8     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef8 thread_start + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196eb3078 __psynch_cvwait + 4
1     libc++.1.dylib 0x0000000195e80cb0 std::__1::condition_variable::wait() + 52
2     My App 0x000000010022c41c _ZN7dropbox11LogUploader17log_upload_threadEv + 2024
3     My App 0x00000001002b18c8 -[DBThreadRunner runThread:] + 136
4     Foundation 0x0000000185975db8 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
5     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4fdc8 _pthread_body + 160
6     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4fd24 _pthread_start + 156
7     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef8 thread_start + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196eb3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 4
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef0 start_wqthread + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196eb3078 __psynch_cvwait + 4
1     libc++.1.dylib 0x0000000195e80cb0 std::__1::condition_variable::wait() + 52
2     My App 0x0000000100365c24 _ZN11DbxUnlinker3runEv + 108
3     My App 0x00000001002b18c8 -[DBThreadRunner runThread:] + 136
4     Foundation 0x0000000185975db8 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
5     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4fdc8 _pthread_body + 160
6     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4fd24 _pthread_start + 156
7     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef8 thread_start + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196eb3c78 __workq_kernreturn + 4
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef0 start_wqthread + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     My App 0x00000001001faf34 mach_exception_callback + 168
1     My App 0x00000001002074d0 exception_server_thread + 304
2     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4fdc8 _pthread_body + 160
3     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4fd24 _pthread_start + 156
4     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef8 thread_start + 0
Thread: Unknown Name

0     libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000196eb3498 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 4
1     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4fdc8 _pthread_body + 160
2     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4fd24 _pthread_start + 156
3     libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000196f4cef8 thread_start + 0
```

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem?